# Symfony2 vendors update blocked on Receiving objects - git pull

Tags: git, symfony

When I run ./bin/vendors install on my project to install a new bundle, I'm blocked by the symfony update :

```
$ ./bin/vendors install
> Installing/Updating symfony
2d4fb8ad502a80af475c7232b5497571ed32a641
remote: Counting objects: 4754, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1709/1709), done.
^Cceiving objects:  16% (591/3690), 164.00 KiB | 310 KiB/s
```

Receiving objects stays à 16% whatever I do. It only does that on this working copy and works fine on the other. I've tried going directly to the symfony folder in the vendor directory and perform a `git pull` however this changes nothing, I've got the same message.

The `git status` command tells me that the symfony working directory is clean.

I can install and update other repositories in the deps file, as long as I remove the symfony entry. However I'm no longer able to update the symfony framework...

Does anyone has a solution to fix this issue ?

**UPDATE**

@kissmyface solution did the trick :

```
./bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your ./vendors/symfony folder, then run `./bin/vendors install` again.

Comment: bin/vendors install --reinstall

Comment: Thanks I'll try that on the guilty computer!

Comment: I've tried @kissmyface solution and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens from time to time because of some troubles on the GitHub side.